# Spring Junit Exception -- java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I have a SpringBoot Project and it has two classes annotated with @SpringBootApplication.
I have written a junit test like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = TestController.class)
public class Test1 {
    @Test
    public void test1(){
    }
}
```

When i run this test am getting exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found multiple @SpringBootConfiguration annotated classes.

I want the test to load only the controller and not the complete context.

Any help on this?

Comment: `@WebMvcTest` causes Spring to look for `@SpringBootConfiguration`, including `@SpringBootApplication`, annotated classes. Probably there are two or more of them in your package structure.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add @ContextConfiguration annotation to your test class.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Application.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = TestController.class)
public class Test1 {
    @Test
    public void test1(){
    }
}
```

Comment: But it is trying to load the complete context. I just wanted to test one controller ignoring all other classes.